# What is confidence reflexivity in association rules?

Tags: data-mining, association-rules, market-basket-analysis

I did not understand the meaning of reflexivity term in association rules. I could not find a basic explanation about it. All I found was just academical researches and they heavy for me. Can anybody explain the confidence reflexivity in association rules?